# why use an odds ratio instead of a proportion

Tags: proportion, standardization, ratio, odds

I would appreciate your advice regarding a 'work' query, in that nobody at work can agree on what appears to be a very simple statistical analysis. I have changed some of the details to protect identities/sensitive work area. Ok so lets say I have 50,000 people on a register in a country, with an illness. We are interested in how many of these people are under 65. Lets say we also have 200 areas within this country, so we are also interested in the percentage per area as well as the national percentage. We checked the register and lets say, we found 500 people (in the whole country) under 65 (hypothetical values only). So we calculated 500/50,000 = 0.01 (*100) = 1%. So we know that 1% of our population under 65 has this illness. This result was reviewed by our internal committee. They rejected the result and said we should be using a standardised odds ratio.

My understanding of an odds ratio is 'the number who experience the event in relation to the number who could experience the event'. The standardised odds ratio the committee recommended is very complex with a number of stages. Our stakeholders have said they don't agree. The committee says this is to standardise due to the different amounts in each area. Could someone please feedback on whether they agree with the method and why. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's a good question, but I am baffled by the committee's recommendation for the simple reason that you have been explicit about your objectives: "We are interested in how many of these people are under 65 ... [and] we are also interested in the percentage per area." That is clear--so what is the problem with estimating these quantities?  Is the committee perhaps considering other unstated or potential uses of the data or other procedures you might not have mentioned?

Comment: Hi whuber,  thanks for your comment, no other info from the committee, just this is the way it should be done for statistical purity. and we can't publish until we do what they say. However my stakeholders simply want to know how many are under 65 are in each area from a service provision perspective. Because being under 65 is a different clinical pathway and a different cost issue.

Comment: "Statistical purity" brings to mind a cabal of statistical priests, holding close their power to sanctify all scientific studies and providing only glimpses of their actions to the masses by means of ritual, sacrifices, and reading entrails :-).

Comment: @whuber That's exactly what happens, but we tend to describe this process with the more polite term "peer review".